# USB DAC Stopped Working

Tags: drivers, usb, sound, pulseaudio, external-soundcard

I have a [Schiit Fulla 3](https://www.schiit.com/products/fulla-1) that I've used on a ThinkPad e480 with Ubuntu 20.04 for several weeks now without issue. Yesterday, the device was no longer showing up in sound settings as an input or output choice. When I `lsusb` with it *not* plugged in, I get:

```
user@e480:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and when I plug it in, I get:

```
user@e480:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 30be:0100 Schiit Audio I'm Fulla Schiit
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

so I know it's detected... Other than semi-regular `apt` updates, I haven't changed anything config-wise. It also isn't showing up in the `pacmd list-sinks` list.

```
user@e480:~$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index:'
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.usb-Ingenic_Semiconductor_CO.__LTD._HD_USB_Camera_Ucamera001-02.mono-fallback>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Nano_8918B12148040506-00.analog-stereo>
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
```

Where should I look next to find out why it's not a choice?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I installed `pavucontrol` and went to the "Configuration" tab, where the "I'm Fulla Schiit" device's profile was set to "Off". Not sure why. Changed back to "Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)" and it's working again.